# getActivity cannot resolve

Tags: android, android-activity, label, android-graphview

That is the code, im trying to make a graph using Graphview, but i cant format the XAxis label into time, so did some search and i copied a code from that page:
http://www.android-graphview.org/dates-as-labels/

```
fetchData process= new fetchData();

Date date[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    graph=(GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

    process.execute();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // manage error ...
    }

    String[] asseX=fetchData.prendix();

    date=new Date[x.length];

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        try {
            date[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(x[i]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(getActivity));
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(x.length);


    }
```

Comment: because getActivity() probably doesn’t exist in the class you are calling it?

Comment: Are you using a fragment?

Comment: but i copied the code from GraphView's page. http://www.android-graphview.org/dates-as-labels/

Comment: `getActivity()` is a Fragment's method . Does your class have any relationship with `Fragment`?

Comment: Please post your entire code. Your just 2 lines is very unclear.

Comment: @UmangBurman ok i tried to add the entire code but it said "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.", so i deleted something that has not importance.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Oh sorry man, im learning android codes in these days and i have difficult in english, why so greedy?

Comment: @KyoR.C. Try the answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(getActivity()));
```

use

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(your_activity_name.this));
```

try it.. and update here if it works..